# Can't bind JavaFX TextField to ListView value

Tags: javafx

I have a JavaFX ListView. When I click on an item in the list, I would like like two...edit controls, a ComboBox and a TextField, to be populated by the appropriate values from the model.

First, my model:

```
public class Recipient {
    private final SimpleStringProperty type = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final SimpleStringProperty address = new SimpleStringProperty();
    // property getters
}
```

In my controller, I have:

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private ComboBox type;
    @FXML
    private TextField address;
    @FXML
    private ListView<Recipient> recipList;

    private final ObservableList<String> types = FXCollections.observableArrayList("SMS", "Email");
    private final ObservableList<Recipient> recips = FXCollections.observableArrayList(Recipient.DUMMYDATA);
    private final ObjectProperty<Recipient> recipient = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        type.setItems(types);
        recipList.setItems(recips);
        recipList.setCellFactory((ListView<Recipient> p) -> new ListCell<Recipient>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(Recipient recip, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(recip, empty);
                final int index = p.getItems().indexOf(recip);
                if (index > -1) {
                    setText(String.format("%s - %s", recip.typeProperty().get(), recip.addressProperty().get()));
                } else {
                    setText(null);
                }
            }
        });
        recipient.setValue(new Recipient());
        recipList.setOnMouseClicked(event -> recipClicked(event));
        type.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(recipient.get().typeProperty());
        address.textProperty().bindBidirectional(recipient.get().addressProperty());
    }

    public void recipClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        final MultipleSelectionModel<Recipient> get = recipList.selectionModelProperty().get();
        final Recipient selectedItem = get.getSelectedItem();
        recipient.setValue(selectedItem);
    }
}
```

When I click on the list, the SimpleObjectProperty is updated as expected, but my controls do now show the data. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bindings bind to the properties belonging to the current recipient at the time the bindings are made. If the value of `recipient` changes, then, for example, `address.textProperty` will still be bound to the `addressProperty()` of the previous value of `recipient`, not the new one.

You can use a listener on recipient to bind and unbind the controls:

```
recipient.addListener((obs, oldRecipient, newRecipient) -> {
    if (oldRecipient != null) {
        type.valueProperty().unbindBidirectional(oldRecipient.typeProperty());
        address.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(oldRecipient.addressProperty());
    }
    if (newRecipient != null) {
        type.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(newRecipient.typeProperty());
        address.textProperty().bindBidirectional(newRecipient.addressProperty());
    }
});
```

As an aside, note that you should not use a mouse listener to respond to changes in selection: it will not work, for example, if the user uses the keyboard to change selection in the list view. You can replace `recipList.setOnMouseClicked(...)` with

```
recipient.bind(recipList.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty());
```

and remove `recipClicked(...)` entirely. (In fact, you might not need `recipient` at all: you can just replace it with `recipList.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty()`.)

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private ComboBox type;
    @FXML
    private TextField address;
    @FXML
    private ListView<Recipient> recipList;

    private final ObservableList<String> types = FXCollections.observableArrayList("SMS", "Email");
    private final ObservableList<Recipient> recips = FXCollections.observableArrayList(Recipient.DUMMYDATA);

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        type.setItems(types);
        recipList.setItems(recips);
        recipList.setCellFactory((ListView<Recipient> p) -> new ListCell<Recipient>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(Recipient recip, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(recip, empty);
                if (empty) {
                    setText(null);
                } else {
                    setText(String.format("%s - %s", recip.typeProperty().get(), recip.addressProperty().get()));
                }
            }
        });
        recipList.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldRecipient, newRecipient) -> {
            if (oldRecipient != null) {
                type.valueProperty().unbindBidirectional(oldRecipient.typeProperty());
                address.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(oldRecipient.addressProperty());
            }
            if (newRecipient != null) {
                type.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(newRecipient.typeProperty());
                address.textProperty().bindBidirectional(newRecipient.addressProperty());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: That did it perfectly. I wasn't a fan of onMouseClicked either, and you fixed that while you were. You're awesome. :) Many thanks!